# Mixed model with serial correlation and random slope?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, mixed-model, panel-data, variogram

I'm making a mixed model for some longitudinal data, where the response is measured fro multiple individuals over time. I have made a model with random intercept, random slope and gaussian serial correlation (like the Diggle model but with random slope).

I only find models with serial correlation and random intercept on the internet. Non of the models I have seen contain serial correlation and a random slope. Is that because it isn't appropriate to make a model like that?

When I plot the variogram for the model with random intercept, random slope and serial correlation, it looks very odd. Further more the points (empirical values) changes if I e.g. plot the variogram for a model without serial correlation. Can anyone explain what happens?

Thank you!

Plots of variograms with:

1) random intercept + random slope + serial correlation

2) random intercept + random slope

3) random intercept + serial correlation

I don't understand why the points are plottet differently or why they decrease. I would assume that the variation should be increasing with the distance.

[image: intercept+slope+serial]
[image: intercept+slope]
[image: intercept+serial]

Comment: It might facilitate helpful responses if you were to post a plot or two illustrating your query.

Comment: Now with plots :)

Comment: Can you clarify whether these are variograms of the residuals associated with each model? Also, what is your time unit and scale? Are all individuals measured at the same time points and if so, how many time points are there? Did you also plot a variogram for the model which ignored the serial correlation? What did it look like?

Comment: I plot them in R by typing plot(variogram(model)). Part of the problem is that I'm not sure exactly what the variogram is. As I understand it takes two time points from the same individual with a specific distance, calculate the difference in the response variable and plot the variance of all these new "observations".
My timeunit is month. Measurements are from every six month. Not all individuals are measured every six month. I have 4200 observations and 1300 individuals.
The second plot is a variogram of a model without serial correlation - only with random intercept and slope.

Comment: Please post the code for your 3 models, and their output.